# Decode My String (Brackets)

Tags: code-golf, string

*Taken from [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803170/decodestring-regex-solution/50803311)*

**Challenge**

Given an encoded string in format `n[s]` where `n` is the amount of times `s` will be repeated, your task is to output the corresponding decoded string.

- `n` will always be a positive number
- `s` can not contain empty spaces
- `strings` only contains letters from the alphabet
- `s` length can be `>= 1`
- encoded format is `number [ string ]`
- string can have nested encoded string `number [ number [ string ] ]`
- return the same string if not encoded

**Examples**

```
2[a]                 => aa
3[2[a]]              => aaaaaa
2[b3[a]]             => baaabaaa
3[a]5[r3[c]2[b]]a    => aaarcccbbrcccbbrcccbbrcccbbrcccbba
a                    => a  // Not Encoded
3                    => 3  // Not Encoded
3a3[b]               => 3abbb
10[b20[a]]           => baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
3[hello]             => hellohellohello
```

**Other test cases**

```
a[a] => a[a] 
a1[a] => aa
3[] =>    // Nothing because are 3 empty string
2[2][a] => 2[2][a]
```

---

**This is my own submission.**

```js
f=i=>(r=/(\d+)\[([a-z]*)\]/g).test(l=i.replace(r,(m,n,s)=>s.repeat(n)))?f(l):l

console.log(f("2[a]"))
console.log(f("3[2[a]]"))
console.log(f("2[b3[a]]"))
console.log(f("3[a]5[r3[c]2[b]]a"))
console.log(f("a"))
console.log(f("3"))
console.log(f("3a3[b]"))
console.log(f("10[b20[a]]"))
console.log(f("3[hello]"))
```

---

If more test cases needed please tell me.

Comment: Usually, someone who suggests a challenge, first tries putting it on the sandbox and doesn't answer it before a few days...

Comment: Can the string consist of multiple characters?

Comment: @JonathanFrech Yes. `string` length is `>= 1`

Comment: New test case: `a[a]`.

Comment: Numbers can apparently be part of the strings, so what about: `12[a]`? `aaaaaaaaaaaa` or `1aa`? And why?

Comment: Other test case: `3[]`

Comment: New test case: `2[2][a]`

Comment: @StewieGriffin `n will always be a positive number` so `12[a]` => `aaaaaaaaaaaa`

Comment: Why is `2[2][a]` returned as unmodified string? Shouldn't it go `2[2][a] -> 22[a] -> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`? Or can `string` only contain lower case alphabet?

Comment: @JungHwanMin no because an `encoded` string follows the format `number [ string ]`, in the case of `2[2][a]` it has the format `number [ number ]`  so it is assumed as is not encoded and `return the same string if not encoded`

Comment: A number can be a string. e.g. `"22"` is a string.

Comment: May we use uppercase instead of lowercase?

Comment: @JungHwanMin Sorry, I have to specify string can only contain letters from the alphabet. My bad

Comment: @Adám Yes.....,

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Your spec doesn't say that the letters are single-case.

Comment: Would `8s` (as an example) be valid input?

Comment: @Shaggy `8s` is a valid input, but not an encoded string. It will output `8s`

Comment: Will the input ever contain unmatched square brackets? e.g., `8s]`.

Comment: @Shaggy. No.....

Comment: This looks mostly good, but the `3[]` test case is unclear to me: if the length of `s` is guaranteed to be at least 1, why is there a test case that has an `s` of length 0?

Comment: [Very similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/154345/42545)

Comment: @ETHproductions Ah, that's the one. I knew I did a similar challenge before, but couldn't remember which. But that's indeed the one I was thinking of.

Comment: @ETHproductions It's not very similar: it's a dupe... What does the fact that the number is after change? I can't close-vote anymore since I close-voted the first round.

Answer (score 2):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 17 + `≡` flag = 28 bytes

```apl
\d+\[\pL*]
∊(⍎⍵M∩⎕D)⍴⊂⍵M∩⎕A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/z8mRTsmOqbARyuW61FHl8aj3r5HvVt9H3WsfNQ31UXzUe@WR11NCBHH//@Noh1juYyjQVQsl1G0kzGYASJNo4OMo51jgWKxsY5cjlzGXMaOxkAOl6FBtJORAVSdh6uPj38slyPIGEdDiGEgg4xigez/jzoXAgA)

Find:

`\d+\[\pL*]` find **d**igit(s) followed by bracketed **L**etters

Replace with:

`⎕A` uppercase **A**lphabet

`⍵M∩` intersection of **M**atch and that

`⊂` enclose (to treat as a whole)

`(`…`)⍴` **r**eshape to length:

`⎕D` **D**igits

`⍵M∩` intersection of **M**atch and that

`⍎` execute (converts text to number)

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)

---

This is equivalent to the Dyalog APL function:

```apl
'\d+\[\pL*]'⎕R{∊(⍎⍵.Match∩⎕D)⍴⊂⍵.Match∩⎕A}⍣≡
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>44</s>  36 bytes

```perl6
{({S{(\d+)\[(<:L>*)\]}=$1 x$0}...*eq*).tail}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##1VLLToQwFN3fr7gLIo8ZgYE4i0GIG3fGje6gi7ZUJWEYhI6ZCeKvY4tMNPP4AG/S9rbnnN5HW4umXA7bVuDH0uURwHqPV3yTC4yHzuqeOivLZ3aWWrerh8SxM9LHxgJ3ht@7ruuId8d2JS3KflC6OylaiTGWRSVad03rFXaA6KGVPc1szFoHzTgxcTW6KZqeZ@LnhBL0IkW28Mvw52paoA09gM7sWV0bQV3SCmdjDJXmy6aZ4l0nSmQUVb2VczTErhZcihztMXbRoi7G@sHtP4T5pImgH4KUEjy2OEFKIUw1SM5A2iBIWXiCK5gpUA/Q6E3ahCkniksI/dU3nHPGLs0UKJ4xLVUt9fBxI/G@0sXlEF5ghqdMGqoszjApYwwWfsoC/6ieqZoT@9eHQPWT62bqFejisNUvNnp46N1bUb0iE5zqr0gboboq1rXcYysbBakvEJBJPbnf)

```perl6
Nil while s{(\d+)\[(<:L>*)\]}=$1 x$0
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##1VLbSsQwEH3PVwy4sDe0l@A@rO6@@Sb7A2keJmm0hbYpSeoF8detibYI2@4HeCBhmHNmyJlJq0y166/AqFq/KHCF8qHtKgc5OoQno@ufZNm0nSM2gsxuYXk4whJuNhBFd/2prOC1KCsF9mOV5dt1xlb3@8fjZp3xz8MigbdF3PcpQw7n8G0QCWWB5DNUAEmZoBPe08KT4ZDA3jJDmeReyzn@1RsppRCXbiQIMwil4K3BSTt4aKTOVU7oBSWdKpH6V8woUQhBkpiJND7zM7iZ4F8nCQ4rD/MMIcHkNzOunY/mYRxiUTbPIJTEzipAo/x4Vd26d7DOeMr/hZSHHr5mCL9060rd2P66/QY) (with `-p`)

### Expanded:

```perl6
Nil                   # silence warning by using Nil rather than 0

while                 # do the above while the following is truish

  s {                 # string replace (implicitly on $_)

    ( \d+ )           # capture a series of digits into $0
    \[
      ( <:L>* )       # capture letters
    \]

  } = $1 x $0         # replace it with the string repeated by the number
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 24 bytes

```
+`(\d+)\[(\p{L}*)]
$1*$2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYw9CoAwDIX3nKOD1cUmeAtvkAaMWlAQFXETz15bdXl/PL4jnPOqLsaqK/xYWc@F36/2Lq2AcaXBGJFVgDibAHJPb8ja8EE8SNpEFBQISCkVcDX3WP@/KSzLJqAZo@6DZRBKyg8)

Updated to support additional test cases. -1 thanks to [@Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m)!

Comment: Fails on [`"3[]"` and `"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"`](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/XztBIyZFWzMmWiOmHEjFcqkYaqkY/f9vHB3LZRRtFBudGAsA "Retina – Try It Online"). (Should give `""` and `"2[2][a]"`.) Replacing `\w+` with `\p{L}*` [fixes these](https://tio.run/##LYtLCoAwDET3OYcLrZs2wVt4gzRg/IBCUSnuxLPXVtzM5zETl2vb1aXUDrWf28Zz7c@7f0zjBSpnKkwJWQWIiwkgj/SFoh1H4kkyE1FQICClXMBZHtH@u3UJ4SihvFEyfQE "Retina – Try It Online").

Comment: I think you can remove the ``\`` before `]`.

Comment: I don't know retina, but is changing `\p{L}` to `\w` valid?

Comment: @tsh That would be invalid for `2[2][a]`

Comment: @tsh I had that before (when that test case didn't exist) and as Mr. Xcoder correctly points out, that test case invalidates it...

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 5, 36 bytes

```
0while s/(\d+)\[([a-z]*)]/$2x$1/e
```

Answer (score 0):

## Japt v2.0a0, 19 bytes

```
e/(\d+).(\l+)]/@ZpY
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ZS8oXGQrKS4oXGwrKV0vQFpwWQ==&input=IjNbYV01W3IzW2NdMltiXV1hIg==)

Comment: `"[11a]"` produces `"[1a"`

Comment: @recursive, according to the spec, that wouldn't be valid input; square brackets can only contain letters.

Comment: `"2[2][a]"` is given as a test case.  I interpret that to mean that the pattern should apply iff the square braces only contain letters.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
è/g1┘+α╣m?╣t╥ó⌂ß─"H║à
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8a2f6731d92be0b96d3fb974d2a27fe1c42248ba85&i=%222[a]%22%0A%223[2[a]]%22%0A%222[b3[a]]%22%0A%223[a]5[r3[c]2[b]]a%22%0A%22a%22%0A%223%22%0A%223a3[b]%22%0A%2210[b20[a]]%22%0A%223[hello]%22%0A%22a[a]%22%0A%22a1[a]%22%0A%223[]%22%0A%222[2][a]%22&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

## [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex), 83 bytes

```
#import base
(\d+)\[([a-z]+)]/Au<$1>,$2,B/_,([a-z]+),/,$1,$1/A,.*?,(.*?)B/$1/#input
```

ReRegex is a language designed around regex. Sadly, it doesn't really understand numbers. So repeating the string is the hardest part of this.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otSk1Prfj/XzkztyC/qEQhKbE4lUsjJkVbMyZaIzpRtypWWzNW37HURsXQTkfFSMdJP14HJq6jr6NiCET6jjp6WvY6GkBC00kfyFfOzCsoLfn/39AgOsnIIDoxNvY/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 158 bytes

```
func[s][b: charset[not"[]"]d: charset"0123456789"until[r: on
parse s[to remove[copy n any d"["copy t any b"]"](insert/dup
c: copy""t do n r: off)insert c]r]s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYzNqsIwEIX3fYphVrq6baNebx/jbodZpPnBQk1KkgoiPntNFSTobs73nTnB6OXfaOLKdoudnaLI1HegTjJEk8j5hMTI@o2wblqx2x9@j384uzSMFDrwrppWC5GSh2DO/mJI@ekKDqS7gkbCZ0zP2GOe3AwumpB@9DxVKs9njZhA@/yzTlq7fTVAceDIyxQGl8DCrSXJ9@odBa2gJC314gOteU9BkOJsmWXhyluUtxS5WoCmpr6tv5ZPZhw9w315AA)

### More readable:

```
f: func [ s ] [
    b: charset [ not "[]" ]
    d: charset "0123456789"
    until [
        r: on
        parse s [
            to remove [ copy n some d "[" copy t any b "]" ]
                ( insert/dup c: copy "" t do n
                r: off )
            insert c ]
        r
    ]
    s
]
```